# No puedo utilizar 2 veces una función recursiva

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, poo

Estoy intentado buscar un nodo de un árbol de forma recursiva...

La primera vez que uso el método `print(t.searchForEuristicID(0))` funciona perfectamente pero la segunda vez me dice:

> TypeError: 'Node' object is not callable

Lo que necesito hacer es lo siguiente:

> **Un método al cual yo le ingrese el ID de un nodo, y buscarlo de forma recursiva... y que me retorne ese nodo en particular.**

Lo logre pero solo la primera vez... para la segunda me devuelve un error.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, childrens, euristic) -> None:
        """
        The first node by 0 the song of 0 by 1 and the new son by 3...
        """
        self.euristic = euristic # This is a numberOrder to resolve a púzzle 
        self.data = data # contain information
        self.childrens = childrens # []

class Three:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        """
        data = puzzle status example [321875649]
        the childrens if you can mouve
        never save 2 equals childern
        childers = [<MovRight><MovDown><MovLeft><MovUP>]
        """
        self.controlList = [] # I never save 2 equal children 
        self.idControl = 0 # Unique id for every node
        self.pivot  = None # Main node 
        self.searchNodeById = None # If you need a node by id

    def addData(self, father, data):
        if self.pivot == None:
            self.pivot = Node(data, [], self.idControl)
            self.controlList.append(data)
            self.idControl = self.idControl + 1
        else:
            if data not in self.controlList:
                self._addData(self.pivot, father, data)

    def _addData(self, pivot, father, data):
        if father == pivot.data:
            pivot.childrens.append(Node(data, [], self.idControl))
            self.controlList.append(data)
            self.idControl = self.idControl + 1
        else:
            for i in pivot.childrens:
                self._addData(i, father, data)

    def searchForEuristicID(self, id):
        """
        Return a node with id
        """
        self.searchForEuristicID = None
        self._searchForEuristicID(self.pivot, id)
        return self.searchForEuristicID

    def _searchForEuristicID(self, node, id):
        if node.euristic == id:
            self.searchForEuristicID = node
        else:
            for i in node.childrens:
                self._searchForEuristicID(i, id)


    def showThree(self):
        """
        Show all data nodes
        """
        self._showThree(self.pivot)

    def _showThree(self, pivot):
        if pivot != None:
            print("Data>",pivot.data, "Eur>",pivot.euristic, "Childs: ", len(pivot.childrens))
            for i in pivot.childrens:
                self._showThree(i)

oneShoot = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,8]
t = Three()
t.addData(None, oneShoot)
t.addData(oneShoot, [1,2,3,4,5,6,9,7,8])
t.addData(oneShoot, [1,2,3,4,9,6,7,5,8])
t.addData(oneShoot, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
t.addData([1,2,3,4,9,6,7,5,8], [3,3,3])

t.showThree()

print(t.searchForEuristicID(0))
print(t.searchForEuristicID(0))
```

La verdad es que no entiendo por que siempre funciona la primera vez, pero no la segunda.

Comment: Tienes una pregunta muy parecida aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/476662/7123 ¿Quizás la respuesta que has recibido en esa otra pregunta resuelve también ésta? Si es así, por favor borra esta. Si no es así aclara en qué esta pregunta es diferente.

Comment: La verdad me funcionó de maravilla la otra respuesta... pero esta vez me causa curiosidad por que no funciona el codigo :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema está en la línea en que asignas `self.searchForEuristicID = node`, dentro de este método:

```py
    def _searchForEuristicID(self, node, id):
        if node.euristic == id:
            self.searchForEuristicID = node
        else:
            for i in node.childrens:
                self._searchForEuristicID(i, id)
```

Ya que estás usando como nombre de atributo `.searchForEuristicID`, que era el nombre de un método, has *reemplazado* ese método con un valor (de tipo `Node`).

La próxima vez que intentes llamar al método `.searchForEuristicID()`, ya no es un método sino un objeto de tipo `Node`, de ahí el error que literalmente te dice que un objeto de tipo `Node` no es "llamable" (no se puede invocar como si fuera una función).

Ten en cuenta que aún corrigiendo ese error no funcionará correctamente la búsqueda porque se retorna en la primera iteración. Respescto a esto has publicado [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/476662/como-retornar-en-una-fuci%C3%B3n-con-recursividad) en la que se da una solución.

Comment: Muchas gracias por explicarme :)